# The API Joda-Time(java) doesnt respect the ISO 8601: bug or feature?

Tags: jodatime, duration

According to their website, the class DUration implements the ISO 8601

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

But let see an example. It is a duration of 14min & 51sec.
In ISO 8601 those code are equivalent :

  PT14M51S

  PT891S

```
    System.out.println("bug "+new Duration("PT14M51S"));
     System.out.println("NO bug "+new Duration("PT891S");
```

The PT14M51S is a real extract for a postgresql database & correct.
The joda-time api just convert everything in sec why ?It seems to dont know anything elese than the keyletter S(theres Y, M, D...)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You need:

```
System.out.println("bug "+new Period("PT14M51S"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, Joda uses "Period" to mean what everybody else calls "Duration" (ISO and Oasis for sure) and adds "Duration" to mean something similar but different. Yes, its really confusing.